Adding vector tiles from GeoServer to QGIS
I have a problem with displaying vector tiles in QGIS. I get the tiles from GeoServer with application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile format enabled.
When I use the link to the tiles as a source for Mapbox GL JS, the data is displayed correctly
map.addSource("countries", {
          type: "vector",
          scheme: "tms",
          tiles: [
            "https://pushkino-maps.ru/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ne:countries@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
          ],
        });


But when I try to connect the link via Vector Tiles in QGIS, the data is displayed in its place, only on the smallest zoom, on the other zooms it is not displayed correctly.
The data is the starting set of the geometry of the countries from GeoServer in projection 4326. In QGIS, the connected layer has a projection of 3857. Project projection 3857.



I tried to change the projection in the link to 3857:
https://pushkino-maps.ru/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ne:countries@EPSG:3857@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf

So the data is not displayed at all. The change to EPSG:4326 only led to other distortions.
I also tried downloading the source data, converting it to 3857, uploading it back to GeoServer and trying to display it. The result has not changed.
What am I doing wrong?

The original Vector tiles are displayed incorrectly due to projection differences. Not sure about the one you converted to 3857, as you do not provide the link.
But in any case, you can use WFS from the same server instead of vector tiles:
https://pushkino-maps.ru/geoserver/ne/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=ne%3Acountries_3857

Adding this works just fine.

WFS really works, but I would still like to figure out vector tiles. The link to the data in 3857 is:
https://pushkino-maps.ru/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0
/ne:countries_3857@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf

From layer properties:
Coordinate Reference Systems
Native SRS
EPSG:3857
Declared SRS
EPSG:3857
SRS handling
Force declared

The thing is that Geoserver does not support 3857. So even if you load it in 3857, it would not really work. It seems like in the newer versions of QGIS it might be possible to edit the CS of the vector tile layer, might be worth trying: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector_tiles/vector_tiles_properties.html

So, try to upgrade and then change the source CS to 4326 or 900913...

Unfortunately, none of the possible combinations of projections 4326, 3857 and 900913 were successful
